# Script/Method to easily add lots of IPs in CentOS?

Tags: bash, networking

I am searching for a script or an easy way to add lots of IP addresses to CentOS.

For example if I type **1.1.1.1** and **2.1.2.1** the script will automatically create the two following files:

1)

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:0
```

-

```
DEVICE=eth0:0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=1.1.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
BROADCAST=1.1.1.1
```

---

2)

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1
```

-

```
DEVICE=eth0:1
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=2.1.2.1 
NETMASK=255.255.255.255 
ONBOOT=yes 
BROADCAST=2.1.2.1
```

Alternatively the easiest option would be if I had a .txt file with a list of IPs

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am currently creating the files manually which is a huge pain to do 50+ at once. I will be doing this every few weeks so I really want a script to help

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with simple bash script like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while read line
do
     filename=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:$count
     echo "DEVICE=eth0:$count\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=$line\nNETMASK=255.255.255.255\nONBOOT=yes\nBROADCAST=$line" > filename
     count=$((count+1))
done < myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How would I run this script?

bash add.sh 1.2.1.2 ?

Comment: Do I just add the IPs to myfile.txt? that doesn't work

Comment: Yes add ips in myfile.txt (one ip per line).

Comment: It doesn't do anything they have permissions.

Is script correct? in /root/ folder I have two files add.sh (script) and myfile.txt with a list of IPs. Both have chmod +x permissions

Comment: do you have write permission in folder "/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts"?

Comment: Yes I am using root account + I set permissions to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

The code that SMA posted did not work for me on CentOS 6.8, however I edited it a bit and this worked:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1
while read line;

do
     echo "Creating eth0:$count with IP: $line" ;
     filename=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:$count
     echo -e "DEVICE=eth0:$count\nBOOTPROTO=static\nIPADDR=$line\nNETMASK=255.255.248.0\nONBOOT=yes\n" > $filename
     chmod 644 $filename
     count=$((count+1))
done < myfile.txt
```